# Inequality chain for a monotonically decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The goal is to solve the following inequality for a monotonically decreasing function $f, f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, where $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers:

$$ \sum_{j = a + 1}^{b} f(j) \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \space dx \leq \sum_{j = a}^{b-1} f(j)$$

So far, I've defined $f$ to be a piecewise constant function, therefore $\exists P = \{ x_0 , x_1 , \space ... \space , x_n \}$ where $a =x_0 < x_1 < \space ... \space < x_n = b$ and $f(x) = c_i \space \forall x \in (x_{i}, x_{i-1})$.

Then, the inequality can be rewritten:

$$ \sum_{j = a + 1}^{b} f(j) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} c_i(x_{i-1} - x_{i}) \leq \sum_{j = a}^{b-1} f(j)$$

I believe the way to approach this lies in the fact that $\sum_{j=a}^b f(j) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} c_i(x_{i} - x_{i-1})$. Then:

$$ (\sum_{j = a}^{b} f(j)) - f(a) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} c_i(x_{i-1} - x_{i}) \leq (\sum_{j = a}^{b} f(j)) - f(b)$$

$$-f(a) \leq0 \leq -f(b)$$

However, I don't understand where to go from here. I understand that $f(a) \geq f(b)$, but am unable to figure out how to deal with the zero...

Answer (score 0):

For any $j=a,a+1,\dots,b-1$ you know from the monotonicity of $f$ that $f(j+1) \le f(x) \le f(j)$ for all $x\in [j,j+1].$ Thus
$$
f(j) \le \frac{1}{(j+1)-1} \int_{j-1}^j f(x) \, dx \le f(j-1).
$$
Now you get the result by summing over $j:$
$$
\sum_{j=a+1}^b f(j) \le \sum_{j=a+1}^b \int_{j-1}^j f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \le \sum_{j=a}^{b-1} f(j).
$$

Comment: Is there no way to proceed on my current approach, have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Your approach is valid and can be made to work, but it uses the intermediate value theorem, which seems too heavy of a gun for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, how could I make it work?